# How to Remove Rs. from float column of cost in C#

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, replace, insert

I am uploading bulk data using excel which has cost column (cost) having values like Rs. 1260. The data type of cost in database is float. I want to insert values in Database without Rs. Below is my repository code for inserting values :

```
public int SetCostDataByDateTime(List<Optimizer> optList)
  {
     try
       {
         int result = 0; 
            foreach (var item in optList)
            {
                string[] timeRes = item.insDt.Split(' ');
                DataTable data = GetData(OptimizerQueries.SELECT_COST_BYDATE_TIME, new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>
                {
                   new KeyValuePair<string, object>("endDateTime", timeRes[0]),
                 new KeyValuePair<string, object>("insTime", timeRes[1]),
                });

                // If already data exist in Table then update else insert.

                var dataRow = data.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("insDateTime")).ToList();
                if (dataRow.Contains(item.insDt))
                {
                    result += UpsertData(OptimizerQueries.UPDATE_COST_DATE, new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> {
                 new KeyValuePair<string, object>("insDt", item.insDt),
                 new KeyValuePair<string, object>("cost", item.cost),

                });
                }
                else
                {
                    result += UpsertData(OptimizerQueries.INSERT_ACTUAL_DATA_BYDATE, new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> {
                 new KeyValuePair<string, object>("insDt", timeRes[0]),
                 new KeyValuePair<string, object>("insTime", timeRes[1]),
                 new KeyValuePair<string, object>("cost", item.cost[1]),

            });
                }



            }
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Error.Log(ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `item.cost` contains value like `Rs. 1234`, then you can split your `item.cost` using `.`, then convert last element of array and convert it into float.

```
var cost = float.Parse(item.cost.split('.').Last());  //cost = 1234
```